# rails scopes to search in an array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, scopes

So I have created a database of fabrics, with a column 'colour' array. For example: a purple and white striped fabric where `colour = ["purple", "white"]`.

I want to create a scope, so the user can search for fabrics that contain a certain colour.

It seems super basic, so I'm surprised I cannot seem to find anything explaining how to use scopes in this way.

I need something similar like the code below, which checks each item in the colour array. Thanks!!

```
scope :with_colour, -> (colour) { where("colour = ?", colour) }
```

Comment: So your using a postgres array column?

Comment: Yes postgres! And managed to find what i was looking for: 
    scope :with_colour, -> (colour) { where(":colour = ANY(colour)", colour: colour ) }

Which is now working for me :)

Answer (score 2):

PostgreSQL have a bunch of useful [array methods](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/functions-array.html) that you can leverage in your Rails applications

In your case you can also do:

```
scope :scope_name, -> (color) { where("colour @> ?", '{color}')}
```

Answer (score 0):

scope :with_colour, -> (colour) { where("colour like ?", "%#{colour}%") }